# How to write multipurpose API for mongoose with node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

**How to write api for below query routes? with help of mongoose, node.js and express.js**

**/search?king=Robb Stark**

- return list of battles where 'attacker_king' or 'defender_king' was
  'Robb Stark'

***Should also work for multiple queries***

**/search?king=Robb Stark&location=Riverrun&type=siege**

***database model is like this:***

_id:5fd8df1c1333e53e88d41f31

name:"Battle of the Shield Islands"

year:"300"

battle_number:"32"

attacker_king:"Balon/Euron Greyjoy"

defender_king:"Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon"

battle_type:"pitched battle"

location:"Shield Islands"

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then you can achieve it through something called as req query in node js API's

```
app.get('/search', async function (req, res) {
    try{
        const query = {}
        if(req.query && req.query.king){
            query.king= req.query.king
        }
        if(req.query && req.query.location){
            query.location= req.query.location
        }

        if(req.query && req.query.type){
            query.battle_type= req.query.type
        }

        const result = await Battles.find(query)

        res.send({
            result:result
        })
    }
    catch(e=>{
        // error condition
        res.send({})
    } )

})
```

Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: Actually I have to check king name from two fields which are attacker_king or defender_king. And I think passing array to find will not work. I tried as well just hit this link:https://codeshare.io/axKWbB and this is my email Id:samruddhashah@gmail.com please contact me